# OpenGL optimize Mesh Drawing (VAO? without indices?)

Tags: c++, opengl

Ok after some timeout I am continuing my studies about OpenGL3.2+, now I am confused about how to optimize something like this:

```
// Verts
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * size, verts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_COORD_ATTRIB);
glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_COORD_ATTRIB,3,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * floatsPerVertex, 0);

// Textures
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * texsize, tex, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB);
glVertexAttribPointer(TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * TexCoords2D, 0);

//add light color info
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ColorBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * colorsize, lightcolor, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(COLOR_ATTRIB);
glVertexAttribPointer(COLOR_ATTRIB, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * ColorInfo, 0);

// Draw
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, size);

// Clean up
glDisableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_COORD_ATTRIB);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(COLOR_ATTRIB);
```

Lets assume this is done for a few meshes, currently each mesh is always pushed like this, bound, buffered and drawn. Needles to say that this is surely no effective approach.

Now when reading (many) tutorials, the one thing I always see is that it is suggested to use VAO to improve that, now my difficulty to understand is- each single tutorial seems to refer in that relation also to indexed drawing. While this method seems to be perfectly fine when using an example with something extremely simple like 2 quads, I am wondering now how one is supposed to create an index for a real complex mesh? Or is it just assumed that this is available (due to .obj file or something).
Also I am confused about if a VAO always needs an index or could it be used without? And if so, would it even make sense without, since I read that an optimization makes use of knowing the index?
You see there is a lot of confusion here yet and I realize this might be a silly question again :)

However, what I want to finally achieve is, instead of pushing each mesh like this, to buffer each mesh once in the memory of the graphics card and redraw it then from the buffer. 
I don't know yet a VAO is even the right approach, but every tutorial I read seems to have VAO's as the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should separate your GRAM writting with glBufferData() from your drawing calls with glDrawArrays(). This significantly drops your performance, because you are basicly copying your data from RAM to GRAM on every drawing call.

For this purpose you can use VAOs:

// setting up buffers

```
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayIndex);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * size, verts, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_COORD_ATTRIB);
glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_COORD_ATTRIB,3,GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * floatsPerVertex, 0);

// Textures
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, TexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * texsize, tex, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB);
glVertexAttribPointer(TEXTURE_COORD_ATTRIB, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * TexCoords2D, 0);

//add light color info
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ColorBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * colorsize, lightcolor, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(COLOR_ATTRIB);
glVertexAttribPointer(COLOR_ATTRIB, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * ColorInfo, 0);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

// your drawing call

```
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayIndex);
 glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, size);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

If you want to draw really big meshes (their size is bigger than GRAM available on you graphic card) you should take interest in splitting your data into small chunks. Having all that data in one big array may cause some nasty memory allocation and rendering issues (believe me - I've been there ;)).

Comment: You exactly said what the biggest problem is in my example and the part I wanted to get rid of. I am really more than surprised that it should be indeed that easy and it also answers my VAO questions to some degree - also thanks for the memory hint, I am sure I will reach that point sooner or later :) will try that and report back

Comment: really cool. I should have asked way earlier here, I think I took this all way more complicated than it is. Wondering why literally every tutorial must bind this to indexed drawing without mentioning such an easy set up. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest your next step should be to turn your vertex atrributes into a struct rather than separate arrays. That way, you're only using one array object, and GPUs much prefer this memory layout.

Beyond that:

Whether you go indexed or not depends heavily on your data; it's not a requirement for fast performance, but it can help; the other option is to use triangle strips, this also reduces the amount of vertex data. If you have multiple meshes in a single array object, you can simply change your vertex attrib pointers to start at a different location in the array object in order to draw a different mesh. Then you're not switching between array objects so much.

Most of these decisions should be driven by your constraints and by performance measurements!

Comment: thanks, this gives me already VERY valuable information and indeed I used triangle strips before :)